# Recycler View + Stars instead of Checkboxes: keeping state while scrolling

Tags: android, checkbox, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-viewholder

I'm having the usual problem with a list + a RecyclerView: when I change the resource file of an item (aka: selected/unselected star icon) and then scroll, other items of the list are keeping the same selected/unselected state for their own star. Plus, when I select an item and then go back, I'm missing the selected/unselected state.

The fullStar and the emptyStar are simple Android Vector images.

Here it is my ListFragment:

```
public class PetrolStationListFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView mPetrolStationRecyclerView;
private PetrolStationAdapter mAdapter;
private int itemPosition;
public static boolean toBeCreated;

private static final String ARG_POSITION = "position";


// Design pattern to instantiate a new fragment.
public static PetrolStationListFragment newInstance(int position) {
    PetrolStationListFragment fragment = new PetrolStationListFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_POSITION, position);

    fragment.setArguments(args);

    return fragment;
}


/********************************************************/

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_petrol_station_list, container, false);

    mPetrolStationRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.petrol_recycler_view);
    mPetrolStationRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    updateUI();

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    updateUI();
}

private void updateUI() {
    PetrolStationDAO petrolStationDAO = PetrolStationDAO.get(getActivity());
    List<PetrolStation> petrolStations = petrolStationDAO.getPetrolStations();

    if (mAdapter == null || toBeCreated) {
        mAdapter = new PetrolStationAdapter(petrolStations);
        mPetrolStationRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        toBeCreated = false;
    } else {
        mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(itemPosition);
    }
}

private class PetrolStationHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    private PetrolStation mPetrolStation;

    private TextView mNameTextView;
    private TextView mAddressTextView;
    private TextView mDistanceTextView;
    private AppCompatImageView mStar;
    private boolean mFavourite;

    public PetrolStationHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        mNameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_station_name_text_view);
        mAddressTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_station_address_text_view);
        mDistanceTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_station_distance_text_view);
        mStar = (AppCompatImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_station_star_image_view);
        mStar.setTag(R.id.list_item_station_star_image_view, "emptyStar");
    }

    public void bindPetrolStation(PetrolStation petrolStation) {
        mPetrolStation = petrolStation;
        mNameTextView.setText(mPetrolStation.getName());
        mAddressTextView.setText("Via Verdi, 19/A");
        mDistanceTextView.setText("300 meters");
        mFavourite = mPetrolStation.isFavourite(mStar);
        Log.d("FAVOURITE", "mFavourite: " + mFavourite);

        //setStarByBoolean();


        mStar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                setStarByTag();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //itemPosition = mPetrolStationRecyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(v);
        Intent intent = PetrolStationPagerActivity.newIntent(getActivity(), mPetrolStation.getId());
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void setStarByBoolean() {
        if (!mFavourite) {
            mStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star_border_orange);
            mStar.setTag(R.id.list_item_station_star_image_view, "emptyStar");
        } else {
            mStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star_orange);
            mStar.setTag(R.id.list_item_station_star_image_view, "fullStar");
        }
    }

    public void setStarByTag() {
        if (mStar.getTag(R.id.list_item_station_star_image_view).equals("emptyStar")) {
            mStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star_orange);
            mStar.setTag(R.id.list_item_station_star_image_view, "fullStar");
        } else {
            mStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star_border_orange);
            mStar.setTag(R.id.list_item_station_star_image_view, "emptyStar");
        }
    }

}

private class PetrolStationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PetrolStationHolder> {

    private List<PetrolStation> mPetrolStations;

    public PetrolStationAdapter(List<PetrolStation> petrolStations) {
        mPetrolStations = petrolStations;
    }

    @Override
    public PetrolStationHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_petrol_station, parent, false);

        return new PetrolStationHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PetrolStationHolder holder, int position) {
        PetrolStation petrolStation = mPetrolStations.get(position);
        Log.d("POSITION", "position: " + position);
        holder.bindPetrolStation(petrolStation);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mPetrolStations.size();
    }

}

}
```

And here a the getter and the setter for the PetrolStation Model class:

```
    public boolean isFavourite(AppCompatImageView star) {
    if (star.getTag(R.id.list_item_station_star_image_view).equals("emptyStar")) {
        mFavourite = false;
    } else {
        mFavourite = true;
    }

    return mFavourite;
}

public void setFavourite(boolean favourite) {
    this.mFavourite = favourite;
}
```

Any hint about how to fix this issue? I'm finding difficult to apply the CheckBoxes examples I've found to my own case.

Comment: RecyclerView reuses its views so whenever the view goes out of focus it is destroyed and therefore all your information goes with it. Anything you do to change this behaviour will result in laggy interface and bad user experience as you will be working against the API and not with it. I had a similar situation a while back . I finally went with a LinearLayout that dynamically inflates views at runtime.

Comment: I've seen plenty of examples resolving this "issue" with CheckBoxes, so I'd like to understand if I may be able to do it with Stars, too. I'd have to do so much work using a LinearLayout that is not worth the trouble.

Comment: One thing you can do is by taking a ArrayList<Boolean> and storing the states on clicking. Right now as you imageview becomes null along with the view your logic s not working

Comment: You have to update the model, if sth. changes in the view. In the `onClickListener` of the star also update the petrol station's favorite state.